# Is there a way to remove "Last message repeated x times" from logs?

Tags: linux, debian, log-files, syslog

I have a script that updates me on any changes to the kernel log on my (Debian) servers.

The problem is that occasionally the log contains lines like:

```
last message repeated 4 times
```

I realize that this is a *feature* to shorten the size of the logs - but would prefer in this case that every instance of the message be logged instead.

**Is there a way to turn off this feature?**

Comment: You should really reconsider :) I have previously had log messages repeating several thousand times per second and you really don't want these writes happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On BSD systems, syslogd has -c option, you could start syslogd -cc to disable this feature.

On linux (checked on Debian), man syslogd lists no such option.

It would seem that there is no way to turn it off under linux:

[http://www.syslog.org/forum/syslog-and-syslogd/disable-'last-message-repeated'-compression-on-lin/](http://www.syslog.org/forum/syslog-and-syslogd/disable-%27last-message-repeated%27-compression-on-lin/)

Answer (score 19):

Control repeat message filtering using $RepeatedMsgReduction in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` (it's `on` by default on Ubuntu systems):

```
# Filter duplicated messages
$RepeatedMsgReduction on
```

More details: https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/action/rsconf1_repeatedmsgreduction.html

Answer (score 4):

On RedHat-family distros, or distros using rsyslogd, you add `-e` to `SYSLOGD_OPTIONS` in `/etc/sysconfig/rsyslog`.

Then restart the `rsyslog` service.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, you can add -e to RSYSLOGD_OPTIONS in /etc/default/rsyslog and "restart rsyslog". It's not documented in the man page, but it works.