# syslog-ng: Disable suppressing repeated messages

Tags: syslog-ng

How can I disable `last message repeated X times` compression in syslog-ng? I use certain log messages as triggers and this effectively hides them. Defining suppress(0) doesn't do what I want.

Comment: Hi, suppress(0) should disable this feature, but that is also the default. Check if it is not enabled in another part of your config.

Answer (score 1):

When I got stuck with this same problem rsyslog was the easiest solution, despite syslog-ng is easy to understand and configure rsyslog has a bit more potential for my point of view.

By the way, if the loging frequency for such event is soy high this might impact on your storage resources and also network/CPU performance. 
It you an add and extract from your syslog-ng config and output may help to get a proper answer.

This may help you:

[Is there a way to remove "Last message repeated x times" from logs?](https://serverfault.com/questions/30303/is-there-a-way-to-remove-last-message-repeated-x-times-from-logs)

Answer (score 0):

The global option, suppress() turns the functionality on and off.

https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/administration-guide/suppress

Comment: OP mentioned this doesn’t work for him ....